# Unable to call javascript function from external.js file

Tags: javascript

I am unable to call my javascript function named as clear which takes a string parameter the parameter value im passing by calling that function on client click.
here is my code please do help me in this

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
    var _whichform = 'login'
    function clear(_whichform)
    {

        switch (_whichform)
        {
        case 'login':
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxUsername.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxPassword.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxFname.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxLname.ClientID%>').value = ''
               break;
          break;
         case 'company':
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxCompname.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxDescptn.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxCompanyEmail.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxStateCo.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxStateCo.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxCity.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxCompanyAddress.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxCpCountryCode.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxCpStateCode.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxPhone.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxCfCountryCode.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxCfStateCode.ClientID%>').value = ''
               document.getElementById('<%=tbxCffax.ClientID%>').value = ''
          break;

        }
    }
</script>
<input id="btnLoginCancel" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clear('login')" class="buttons"/>
```

Comment: you have to use the 'Id' of the element there. Are you using JSP?

Comment: Do you know that in js you have to add a semicolon `;` at the end of a code line? Also, you have two `break` statements in continues lines.

Comment: You sir came from Python didn't you?

Comment: Maybe it could be useful the `reset` button for this case. `<input type="reset" value="Reset" />`

Comment: How about simple `#_whichform.reset()`?

Answer (score 2):

You missed a semicolon.

```
var _whichform = 'login';
```

Answer (score 0):

clear() is a native function in the browser.  Name your function e.g. myclear, and it will work (provided the field with the id's named are correct).

clear is a method on window.document.  In SOME browsers (e.g. chromium), the onclick will be executed in that context.  This can be seen e.g. by adding onclick="console.log(clear)", and you will get something like: function clear() { [native code] }

Then it's always a good idea to end all statements with semicolon, to avoid later mixups with newlines etc.

Comment: No conflict, `clear` is a method of `document`, not `window`.

Comment: In the context of onclick on a html-element, clear is the native function.  Try adding onclick="console.log(clear)" and it will state the navite function rather than the user specified.

Comment: True, but when clicking the button (== window context), `clear()` is a user defined function, not a native function. **EDIT** This seems to vary in different browsers...

Comment: i renamed it to myclear as you have suggested but it still not working

Comment: If you have fixed all commented on here and it still doesn't work, the problem is not with the code presented.  Make sure that the IDs are really inserted instead of the <% %>-code.  If you see the <% in the source code on the html-page, your problem lies with your template engine, not the js itself.

I have copied your code, (changed the name to myclear, added semicolons, removed the double break…) changed one of the IDs to 'test', added an input with id 'test', and it works well in both chromium and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a semicolon in the second line
it should be
`var _whichform = 'login';` 
Also for testing and debugging its always better to use `IE` since it would have shown that you have missed the semicolon in your second line.

Answer (score 0):

There are few points needs your attention.

**1.** If  this is the external JS file then you write it wrong,  there is no need of writing
`<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags in external js file it throws the Syntax error. you can directly start from writing a function and be careful in calling js file (path etc.)

**2.** You missed semicolons at several places in your js file and there is no need of defining 
**Var _whichform** because you are already passing the parameter at the time of calling the function.

**3.** From Developers point of view it’s better to test your code on Firefox using firebug 
It certainly helps in debugging and writing better javascript code.